# Why does the value of the "parent" get the sum of the values of the "children" and not the value of itself in the TreeMap?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, amcharts, treemap, amcharts4

I could not understand why when a "parent" has value, he still does not receive his own value and still receives as the value the sum of the values of "his children".

**Although it is recorded in the doc that when a "parent" has a value he does not inherit the values of his children:**
[image]
Amcharts Doc:https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/chart-types/force-directed/

**Code:**

chart:

```
let chart = am4core.create("chartdiv",am4charts.TreeMap)
```

InputJson:

```
const jsonData =[{
  "name": "First",
  "value": 2390, //Parent value
  "children": [
    { "name": "A1", "value": 0.4 }, //children value
    { "name": "A2", "value": 0.4 }, //children value
    { "name": "A3", "value": 0.1917355900000002 } //children value
  ]
}, {
  "name": "Second",
  "value": 5933, //Parent value
  "children": [
    { "name": "B1", "value": 0.2332 }, //children value
    { "name": "B2", "value": 0.323 }, //children value
    { "name": "B3", "value": 0.122332 } //children value
  ]
}]
```

TreeMap levels:

```
const level1 = chart.seriesTemplates.create("0");
let level1_column = level1.columns.template;
const level1_bullet = level1.bullets.push(new am4charts.LabelBullet());

level1_bullet.label.text =  "{value}";  //The value is the sum of the values of all his children.


const level2 = chart.seriesTemplates.create("1");
let level2_column = level2.columns.template;
const level2_bullet = level2.bullets.push(new am4charts.LabelBullet());

level2_bullet.label.text =  "{value}";  //The value is of the child.
```

Amcharts Doc TreeMap: https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/chart-types/treemap/

**Console:**

I need the parent's value column to be a red value object and not a yellow object.(As in InputJson)
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, and I found your question on GitHub as an [issue](https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/issues/2925), but I don't like the fact that the only answer I found about this problem, is "*this is not possible*".

**You cannot set the parent value to be a custom number, because it's always calculated from the children values.** It's true.

**However**, you can calculate custom item values for the purpose of displaying your data, and use custom tooltip to show the real values.

Just to give you an example:

In my case, I added the children dynamically on hit event, so initially the parent had its own value, but after inserting children with values that are not related to its parent value, the whole chart was messed up.

Instead of using the real data as item value, I calculated it based on the parent's item value and the children's real values:

- For the root element, I used a fix number (e.g. 10000).
- For every item that has parent, I calculated it's item value by dividing the parent's item value with the sum of the children's real values, and multiplying it with the item's real value. It gives a value that is proportional to the parent and the other children.

But this method is also useful, when you have items with 0 or very small value, but you want to show them with a fix value. I also found a [question](https://github.com/amcharts/amcharts4/issues/1946) about this on github, with the same "*this is not possible*" answer.

I hope this answer will be helpful for someone.